# VSCode Syntax Highlighting not working with Vue / Vetur

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, vetur

For the last week or so, every .VUE file I work with has no syntax highlighting. I usually have the extension **Vetur** to help with synthax highlighting and other tweaks to .VUE files.

Things I've tried so far:

- uninstall/reinstall Vetur
- change file associations in VScode
- make sure .vue files have no errors

[image: ][1]]

Comment: This totally worked! I didn't know you could force VScode to reinstall extensions. This apparently works when doing a manual uninstall/reinstall of the extension didn't work.


`Run command: Developer: Reinstall Extension for Vetur.`

Comment: I didn't have the `Vetur` enabled...

Comment: These (and many others) github links no longer work

Answer (score 16):

You can install 'Vue 3 Support - All In One' from extensions in vs code. Then the issue with syntax highlighting will fix.

Answer (score 5):

1. Disable Volar/Vetur extension
2. Install and enable Vue 3 Support Extension
3. Reload VSCode

Answer (score 0):

As i see for lang="pug" there is no needs to use other extension as like below:

https://vuejs.github.io/vetur/highlighting.html#custom-block

So I think the problem may be on your project file, please check new vue project to be sure that the problem is not from your files and config of the project !

Answer (score 0):

According to [Vetur's "No Syntax Highlighting & No Language Features working" FAQ](https://vuejs.github.io/vetur/guide/FAQ.html#no-syntax-highlighting-no-language-features-working), what you can do to resolve the issue is:

> try disabling all other Vue related extensions.

or

> - Run command: `Developer: Reinstall Extension` for Vetur.
> - Remove Vetur in your [extensions folder](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-marketplace#_common-questions) and do a clean reinstall.
> - (Windows): Try removing & reinstall Vetur with admin privilege.
> - If nothing above works, download the [latest pre-packaged vsix file](https://github.com/vuejs/vetur/releases) and [install through vsix](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-marketplace#_install-from-a-vsix).

Answer (score -3):

As **Sebastian Brosch** said in a reply

This worked for me:
https://github.com/vuejs/vetur/blob/master/docs/FAQ.md#no-syntax-highlighting--no-language-features-working

TLDR: Run command reinstall command in vscode and select vetur extension