# Vue not highlighting components inside template on vscode

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, vue-component, syntax-highlighting, highlight

I used to have all my imported components inside the  in a different color compared to other regular html components. But is does not work anymore.

Already tried uninstalling and installing all extensions and used vue 3 all in one, it did not worked.

[image]

it used to be planning-top-menu in blue and div in pink

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, this happens as a glitch when the memory used by VSCode gets too full with undo states. Other times, it's because VSCode can't case match the component to the import (i.e. `import Thing from './Thing.vue'` !== `<thing/>`)

In most cases, Vetur takes a nap and doesn't wake up...
See [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63230774/vscode-syntax-highlighting-not-working-with-vue-vetur).

Working with Vue with Typescript, I found that if you don't wrap a prop-passed-as-type in parenthesis, the syntax highlighting below will get messed up:

```
<ThingWithTypedProp
  :typed-prop="foo as Bar"
/>
vs
<ThingWithTypedProp
  :typed-prop="(foo as Bar)"
/>
```

[Props-passed-as-type Syntax highlighting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIHhf.png)

This does not apply if you are working with pure Vuejs